# Python Asynchronous Websocket Method Returns Future

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I have an `async` method that I am trying to use to return data from a NodeJs application websocket interface.

When the method runs though I am just receiving a `<Future pending>` message within a websockets object.

What do I need to change in order for the method to receive and print the actual message from the server?

```
import asyncio
import json
import asyncws
import websockets
import requests

...
...
...

async def inject():
    ws = await asyncws.connect(url + get_sid())
    print("Sending...")

    payload = base_query + f"(SELECT substring((SELECT token FROM AuthTokens WHERE UserId = 1),1,1))=3 #"
    payload = string_to_json(payload, token)
    payload = f'42["checkEmail", {payload}]'

    ws.send(payload)
    print("Sent...")

    print("Receiving...")
    reply = ws.recv()

    if reply is None:
        print("NoneType reply")
    else:
        print(reply)
        for r in reply:
            print(r)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(inject())
asyncio.get_event_loop().close()
```

Output:

```
Sending...
Sent...
Receiving...
<generator object Websocket.recv at 0x7fbb1813eb30>
<Future pending>
```

Comment: You need to put `await` in front of both `ws.send` and `ws.recv` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websockets uses Python's `asyncio` to manage concurrency and I/O.

The `websocket.send` and `websocket.recv` are async functions. That means you need to `await` these to get the value.

In your code, you need to change `ws.send(payload)` to `await ws.send(payload)` and `ws.recv()` to `await ws.recv()`.

You can read the documentation for Websockets here: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#websockets.protocol.WebSocketCommonProtocol.recv